# Is delta lake good for too frequent updates to same record?

Tags: delta-lake

I'm new to Delta Lake and I would really appericiate if someone can help eveluate delta lake for a scenario.
We have a customer data platform where we have two tables: customer, event.

**We run queries like:**

- Customers of India(customer table attribute filter) who Viewed This product(event "Product Viewed").
- Basically join of event and customer table.

**Event table:** is just a fact table. Once ingested, never updated.

**But the customer table is being updated a lot:**

- For example, customer attributes like "last page visited". Meaning a row might get updated many many times in minute while cusotmer is browsing our website.
- We update "Loyalty Score" attribute of customers every day morning.

Customer table might have roughly 1 billion plus records, 1 Million ingests/updates daily.

With such high rate of updates to same record in delta table, should we consider delta table or should we think of someting else.

Comment: what about not updating the records, but just do append-only? Because in this case, you will get more information, like, how people navigate through site, etc. - it may help quite a lot for optimizing website, marketing, etc.